# How to get the total price for a specific product id and service id in sql?

Tags: mysql, sql

**How to get the total price for a specific product id and service id in SQL?**

| product_id | service_id | price |
| --- | --- | --- |
| NULL | 1 | 500 |
| 2 | NULL | 300 |
| NULL | 3 | 150 |
| 4 | NULL | 200 |

**expected output:**

| product_total | service_total |
| --- | --- |
| 500 | 650 |

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

We can use a case statement to determine whether we want to include price in the total for each column.

> ```
> create table sales(
> product_id int,
> service_id int,
> price int);
> insert into sales values
> (NULL,    1,  500),
> (2,   NULL,   300),
> (NULL,    3,  150),
> (4,   NULL,   200);
> ```

> ```
> select
>   coalesce(product_id, service_id) "id",
>   case when product_id is null then 0 else price end products,
>   case when service_id is null then 0 else price end services
> from sales
> order by coalesce(product_id, service_id);
> ```

> ```
> id | products | services
> -: | -------: | -------:
>  1 |        0 |      500
>  2 |      300 |        0
>  3 |        0 |      150
>  4 |      200 |        0
> ```

> ```
> select
>   sum(case when product_id is null then 0 else price end) product_total,
>   sum(case when service_id is null then 0 else price end) service_total
> from sales
> ```
>
> ```
> product_total | service_total
> ------------: | ------------:
>           500 |           650
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=c5e5f2491f56efaf16980851acbe6af7)*

Comment: yes, sir already done thanks again :)